Anydice - Complex dice pool system, with d6s, d8s, d4s, and half-sucessess
I'm a complete dumbass when it comes to math and stats, but really want to design ttrpgs.
My game uses a dice pool of d6s, that can be upgraded or downgrade to d8s or d4s.
Players will roll mostly d6s but with some d8s or d4s mixed in eventually.
Results above 6+ count a success, results 4-5 count as half a success, and two halves add together to make one full success, and results 3-1 count as a fail.
So what I hoped to do is make a formula on anydice where I can:

Count the probability of getting an X number of successes
Control how many dice is rolled
Control how many dice of each type is rolled (between d4s, d6s and d8s)
Count the probability of having "half" a success
Add 4s and 5s, the half-successes, together to create one success.

I don't know if this is even possible, and it may be too ambitious regardless, but thank you, kind souls, anyway!

Some tips on handling these kinds of mechanics in AnyDice efficiently:

Count half-successes, not full successes. AnyDice can only handle whole numbers.

Relabel the sides of your dice with the number of (half-)successes they count as.


You can either do this relabeling manually, like this:
FOUR:  d{0, 0, 0, 1}
SIX:   d{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}
EIGHT: d{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}

output 1dFOUR + 2dSIX + 1dEIGHT named "half-successes with 1d4, 2d6 and 1d8"

or write a custom helper function to do it, like this:
function: relabel ROLL:n {
  if ROLL >= 6 { result: 2 }
  if ROLL >= 4 { result: 1 }
  result: 0
}

output 1d[relabel d4] + 2d[relabel d6] + 1d[relabel d8] named "half-successes with 1d4, 2d6 and 1d8"

Ps. If you're only interested in the number of full successes, you can divide the result by 2 before outputting it, like this. Division in AnyDice rounds towards zero:
output (1dFOUR + 2dSIX + 1dEIGHT) / 2 named "full successes with 1d4, 2d6 and 1d8"


If you want to round up instead of down, add 1 to the result before dividing by 2

Thank you very much for this solution! This is very simple and understandable, simply perfect for my needs <3

So one thing to grasp is that anydice might be more detail than you need.
Start by looking at the mean and variance of each die.  I'll call your method of counting to be dN*.
Mean is easy to work out.  Add up the value for each possibility, then divide by the die size.
Variance is a bit different.  You need the Mean, then you subtract the value of each possibility from the mean and square it.  And then divide by the die size.
These two gives you almost all of the information you really need about your random number generator (not quite everything, but they are a great summary).
To do the math:
Mean(d4*) is 1/8 = (.5)/4
Var(d4*) = (1/8^2 + 1/8^2 + 1/8^2 + 3^2/8^2)/4 = 12/256 = 3/64 = Mean(d4*) * 0.375
Mean(d6*) is 1/3 = (.5*2+1)/6
Var(d6*) is (3/3^2 + 2/6^2 + 2^2/3^2)/6 = (12/6^2 + 2/6^2 + 4^2/6^2)/6 = 5/36 = Mean(d6*) * 0.4166...
Mean(d8*) is 1/2 = (.52+31)/8
Var(d8*) is (3/2^2 + 4/2^2)/8 = 7/32 = Mean(d8*) * 0.4375
The Var(dN*)/Mean(dN*) is pretty constant (around 0.4).  So there isn't going to be a super-large distribution difference between 8d4* and 2d8*; both are mean 1 with variance around 0.8.
There is going to be a skew difference, and low probability tail on the d4s that generate more successes, but it won't be very large.
Here is an anydice program (from the other answer) showing the probability curves of 8d4 and 2d8: click on "at most" and "graph" to get a visual comparison.
Your system is a bit different than one looking like:

d8: +1 success for every 1. (E: 1/8)
d6: +1 success for every 1 and 2. (E: 1/3)
d4: +1 success for every 1 and 2. (E: 1/2)

due to a noticeably different variance, and the fact you round-down on half-successes.

So what your are saying is, depending on the set of dice I choose to roll the result is practically the same, right?

@DiáriodoMestre I'm saying that 8d4* = 3d6* = 2d8* and the result would be difficult to distinguish between by just watching the game narrative.  Using the anydice above, use https://anydice.com/program/3a28c and select "graph, at least" and notice how the curves are right on top of each other (the smaller dice have a long tail, but that long tail is all very low probability)
